# Collapsingtoolbar With Recyclerview and SwipeRefreshLayout Not working Properly

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a Collpasing toolbar and a RecyclerView that has multiple layout. When I scroll up its fine. But when scrolling up, the SwipeToRefresh will Trigger.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/juandirection_samplepic"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_category_selected" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The SwipeToRefresh should work when the user hit the top and when you hold down on the screen, swipe to refresh will trigger. In my case, every swipe(down), swipe to refresh will trigger. Any solution for my case?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".CategorySelected"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_category_selected">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvPOI"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where do you have the  SwipeRefreshLayout inside an activity or fragment ? are inside the toolbar there is a TabLayout?.. please put what  ave you tried

Comment: its inside a coordinatorlayout.. Haven't tried anything yet so far. Just got back to work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
             if(verticalOffset == headerhight){
//headerhight is the offset when appbarlayout height when expanded completely.
                 mSwipeLayout.setRefresh(false);
             }else{
                 mSwipeLayout.setRefresh(true);
             }
        }
    });
```

But this one has a bug.

Comment: What's the bug then?

Comment: Do not state something has a bug without adding the bug.